# Why does it take such a long time to return to Matlab after reaching the last line of a MEX file?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

It takes roughly ~14 seconds to return to the matlab command line after the last line of my MEX file has finished executing.

When timing of the MEX file from matlab:

```
D=rand(14000)+rand(14000)*1i;
tic;
[A B C]=myMexFile(D);
toc
disp(datetime('now'));
```

The output is:

```
Elapsed time is 35.192704 seconds.
   15-Sep-2018 16:51:35
```

While timing the MEX file from within C using the following minimum working example:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>

double getHighResolutionTime() {
    struct timeval tod;
    gettimeofday(&tod, NULL);
    double time_seconds = (double) tod.tv_sec + ((double) tod.tv_usec / 1000000.0);
    return time_seconds;
}

void double2cuDoubleComplex(cuDoubleComplex* p, double* pr, double* pi,int numElements){
    for(int j=0;j<numElements;j++){
        p[j].x=pr[j];
        p[j].y=pi[j];
    }
}

void cuDoubleComplex2double(cuDoubleComplex* p, double* pr, double* pi,int numElements){
    for(int j=0;j<numElements;j++){
        pr[j]= p[j].x;
        pi[j]= p[j].y;
    }
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    double tic=getHighResolutionTime();

    int m=(int)mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    int n=(int)mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    int SIZE=m*n;

    //get pointers to input data from matlab and convert to 
    //interleaved (Fortran) ordering
    cuDoubleComplex *Gr= (cuDoubleComplex*) mxMalloc(SIZE*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    double2cuDoubleComplex(Gr,mxGetPr(prhs[0]),mxGetPi(prhs[0]),SIZE);


    //modify the input data, allocate output matrices, and convert 
    //back to split (matlab) ordering.
    Gr[0].x=0.0;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,m,mxCOMPLEX);
    cuDoubleComplex2double(Gr,mxGetPr(plhs[0]),mxGetPi(plhs[0]),SIZE);

    Gr[0].x=1.0;
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,m,mxCOMPLEX);
    cuDoubleComplex2double(Gr,mxGetPr(plhs[1]),mxGetPi(plhs[1]),SIZE);

    Gr[0].x=2.0;
    plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,m,mxCOMPLEX);
    cuDoubleComplex2double(Gr,mxGetPr(plhs[2]),mxGetPi(plhs[2]),SIZE);

    mxFree(Gr);

    double elapsed=getHighResolutionTime()-tic;mexPrintf("%f\n", elapsed);
    time_t current_time = time(NULL);
    char* c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);
    mexPrintf("time at end of MEX file %s\n", c_time_string);
}
```

The output is:

```
21.676793
time at end of MEX file Sat Sep 15 16:51:21 2018
```

Matlab returns a time of 35.19s while the MEX file actually takes 21.67s to reach the last line. The date and time are ~14 seconds apart i.e. 16:51:21 for the MEX file and 16:51:35 for matlab.

The outputs are very large matrices, but they are successfully allocated and initialized before the last line of the MEX file. I cannot think of anything else. What is causing this behaviour and how do I avoid it?

Update: I've tried this on more machines and the time discrepancy is still there.

Update: I've replaced the above pseudo-code with a minimum working example. Note that the code the above code does not actually use any GPU functionality. I'm including the cuComplex.h header just to use the cuDoubleComplex datatype.

Comment: Maybe garbage collector?  Try removing parts of your code until it stops happening

Comment: @ThP I've tried getting rid of mxFree, as well as replacing mxMalloc and mxFree with malloc and free. Same result.

Comment: Thanks for updating with a minimal example. I think I know what could be going on. I suspect that you use MATLAB R2018a or later, and compile the MEX-file in R2017b-compatibility mode (which is the default). R2018a stores complex numbers in one single memory block, as opposed to 2 separate blocks as it did in earlier versions. Compiling MEX-files in compatibility mode means that MATLAB copies the complex data over to the old format before running the MEX-file, and copies any complex output data over to the new format. I bet this is the delay you’re seeing!

Comment: @Cris Luengo you nailed it! That was exactly the problem. I thought I was submitting jobs to run on a pre-R2018a version of Matlab, but it turns out there was a bug in my submission scripts and the code was actually running on R2018a...! I'll update the question with this caveat however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of MATLAB R2018a, [MATLAB internally stores complex arrays in an interleaved format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/matlab/matlab_external/do-i-need-to-upgrade-my-mex-files-to-use-interleaved-complex.html). In previous versions, MATLAB used two separate memory blocks to store complex data: one for the real values and one for the imaginary values. In a MEX-file, you used `mxGetPr()` and `mxGetPi()` to get pointers to these two memory blocks (these functions are referred to as the "Separate Complex API").

Starting with R2018a, with the new internal data representation, MEX-files can be compiled in two different ways:

1. A compatibility mode (this is the default, you can add `-R2017b` to the `mex` command to force this mode), where you can compile old MEX-files without modification. These MEX-files thus use the "Separate Complex API". MATLAB copies complex data from its new interleaved representation into separate real and imaginary memory blocks before executing the MEX-file code, and copies any complex output arrays back into the interleaved format. This obviously costs some time. This is the cause of the delay observed by the OP.
2. A new mode (add `-R2018a` to the `mex` command), where MEX-files use [the new "Interleaved Complex API"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-support-for-interleaved-complex.html). That is, the MEX-file code is adapted to use the new interleaved complex format. Since most C and C++ libraries you might want to call from your MEX-file use an interleaved format, this is actually a big advantage.

The solution to avoid the large delay at the start and end of MEX-files that process complex arrays is to rewrite them to use the new "Interleaved Complex API". This requires [the following changes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/matlab/matlab_external/upgrade-mex-files-to-use-interleaved-complex.html):

- Find all uses of the `mxGetPr()` and `mxGetPi()` functions. The latter no longer is available. `mxGetPr()` now throws an error if the input array is complex-valued. Instead, use [`mxGetData()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetdata.html), which will return a pointer to the complex interleaved data. Note that they recommend you don't use it for numeric data, it seems [they prefer you use the new "typed data access functions"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-matrix-api-typed-data-access.html). `mxGetImagData()`, like `mxGetPi()`, no longer exists.
- The same is true for the functions that set the data pointer (`mxSet...()`).
- Don't forget to check if the input array actually is complex and of type double, using [`mxIsComplex()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxiscomplex.html) and [`mxIsDouble()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisdouble.html).
- The function [`mxGetElementSize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetelementsize.html) now returns 16 for complex double data, not 8 like it used to.
- Compile your MEX-file using `mex -R2018a <filename>`.

[Here are some more troubleshooting tips](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/troubleshooting-mex-api-incompatibilities.html).